# When post is first made, it says "viewed 1 times"

Tags: bug

This is a *very* small bug, which might not even be worth fixing, but I thought I would throw it out there because it *is* a mistake. When I posted a question, I noticed in the 'viewed' section on the right side it used the plural of time, when it should have been singular. Screenshot posted below:

---

[image]

---

I know this is very minor, and I'm not sure if it is at all useful, but it seems *very* easy to fix, so I thought I would throw it out there. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. Yes, the involving parties are aware of it. However, it is a rather insignificant bug. As such, it is fairly low on the priority order.

That said, this is not a problem specific to Game Dev Stack Exchange; While it may *seem* easy to fix, all you can do is raise the concern. However, you would not raise the concern, here. You would raise it at the Stack Exchange meta, as it pertains to the general Stack Exchange collective.

You would also be sure to observe that [such reports have already been made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times). Again, they are aware of it; but such fixes are low in priority. The accepted response was a quote from Jeff Atwood, and the report was marked as "complete".

Here is said quote:

[image: Jeff Atwood writes, via Twitter, "Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S", posted at 9:33 PM - 31 Jan 2009.]

Answer (score 0):

I think this covers it. I know it's a link-only answer, BUT it is to stack exchange. So if THAT link is dead...

[What is the story of Jeff Atwood and the pluralization 'Bug'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug)

:)

Comment: Did you just perform an edit to add a smiley face?

Comment: I did, actually. I wanted to make sure it was clear I wasn't saying the guy asking the question was being a dork. :)